# Store and Load dropdown selection from localStorage

Tags: javascript, cookies, local-storage

I'm trying to save an option value to localstorage so that when a different page is opened or you return to the website the option is saved and the same css file is used as when last time the website was opened.

This is what I've done so far but I haven't been able to get it to work:

HTML:

```
<select name="style" id="style" onChange="changeCSS();">
    <option id="standard" value="standard">Standard</option>
    <option id="alternative" value="alternative">Alternative</option>
</select>
```

Javascript:

```
function changeCSS() {
    "use strict";
    var select, stylesheet, save;

    select = document.getElementById("style");
    stylesheet = document.getElementById("stylesheet");

    if(localStorage.getItem('save')) {
        select.options[localStorage.getItem('save')].selected = true;
    }

    if (select.value === "standard") {
        stylesheet.href = "include/global.css";
        localStorage.setItem('save', select.value);
    } else if (select.value === "alternative") {
        stylesheet.href = "include/alternative.css";
        localStorage.setItem('save', select.value);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Managed to get it to work in the end. This is what I did:

HTML:

```
<select name="style" id="style" onChange="changeCSS();">
    <option id="standard" value="standard">Standard</option>
    <option id="alternative" value="alternative">Alternative</option>
</select>
```

Added this to body tag:

```
<body onload="autoCSS();">
```

Javascript:

```
var select, stylesheet;

function changeCSS() {
    "use strict";

    select = document.getElementById("style");
    stylesheet = document.getElementById("stylesheet");

    if (select.value === "standard") {
        stylesheet.href = "include/global.css";
        localStorage.setItem('save', select.value);
    } else if (select.value === "alternative") {
        stylesheet.href = "include/alternative.css";
        localStorage.setItem('save', select.value);
    }
}

function autoCSS() {
    "use strict";

    select = document.getElementById("style");
    stylesheet = document.getElementById("stylesheet");

    if (localStorage.getItem('save')) {
        select.options[localStorage.getItem('save')].selected = true;
        changeCSS();
    }
}
```